# Unable to click element with Puppeteer

Tags: screen-scraping, puppeteer

URL : https://auto.ru/catalog/cars/all/?page_num=1

JS code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://auto.ru/catalog/cars/all/?page_num=1', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

        await page.click('#confirm-button');

        await page.waitFor(1000);

        await page.screenshot({path: './data/example.png'});

        await browser.close();

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})();
```

When I run this code there are no errors but also there is no click, I stay at the same page.

[image]
How can I make a click to the left blue button with Puppeteer (open the URL with incognito mode to see the buttons)?

Comment: Incognito doesn't work for me, I see the listing right away. Right-click the button and "Inspect", then in DevTools Elements right click the node and Copy - selector. Use that selctor in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working fine. You just need to wait for the navigation to complete before taking the snapshot. Also, always make sure the element appears before trying to click on it:

```js
await page.waitForSelector("#confirm-button");
await Promise.all([
    page.click('#confirm-button'), 
    page.waitForNavigation()
]);
await page.screenshot({path: './data/example.png'});
```